# How to hide a row of a DataGridView when clicking on a DataGridViewColumnButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have added a `DataTable` to the `DataGridView` in WinForms SystemTray App. I have two buttons in each row, like "public" and "Ignore". When I click any of the two buttons the particular row which the buttons have the same index must be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the DataGridViewRow in which a user clicked a button use the DataGridView's `CellClick` event, like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    // After you've verified that the column clicked contains the button you want to use to hide rows...

    CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
    currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();

    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Visible = false;

    currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
}
```

Notice that you need to suspend data binding to set the row's `Visible` property to false.

To display all the rows you've hidden rebind your DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;         
dataGridView1.DataSource = yourDataTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Sir.Well Sir,it is working Perfect.And what i need now is when click a DataGridViewButtonColumn means a button,then only it should be hide not when i click the total row.